# Only GET request is working with basic spring security authentication

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http, csrf

I am trying to secure my endpoints but only get request works with default username and password,

Here is my security configuration file:

```
package com.expense_tracker.expenseTracker.Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
        }).csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }
}
```

I only want authenticated users to access the endpoint I will later add the code to authenticate users with username but right now I am using default spring username and password.

My DB doesn't have any roles column so I am not assigning any roles to users.

GET request works with default username and password but for any other requests I get 401 status code.

I searched and found many stackoverflow question about this but all had same answers.

1. Disable csrf which I already did.
2. Check whether the configuration file is available for component scanning.

   [config file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfkKQ.png)
3. Also I tried permitting every endpoints without authentication just for testing.

   ```
   package com.expense_tracker.expenseTracker.Config;

   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class SecurityConfig {

       public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

           return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
               auth.requestMatchers("/expense-tracker/**").permitAll().anyRequest();
               // auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
           }).csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
       }
   }
   ```

   Also gives 401 status code.